# CSS how to make div visible on focus not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to make div element visible on focus but it is not working.  If i change focus to hover it works

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/9bo81jyy/8/

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navtabs">
      <li>
        <a href="showMe/1">
          <div class= "inside">
            <div tabindex="0" class="delete">
              <button tabindex="-1" class="fa-times-circle"> </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav > ul.navtabs > li > a > div:focus .delete{
  display: inline !important;
}
.delete{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Focus happens when you `<tab>` to an element. `<div>` elements are not focussable by default (Google 'tabindex html'). It is also a bad idea to put a `<button>` in a link. You do not want to go to `showMe/1` when you press that `<button>` right? :)

Comment: button is a close icone. Added tab index for div to be focusable

Comment: Aye, but the "close" icon sits within the "showMe/1" link which means that any click on the button might trigger the link instead. Maybe the button action won't get executed in this case. It is in general better to move it outside the link tag, since it serves it's own purpose (or well, so I think :)).

Comment: You can not nest "interactive" elements such as `a` and `button` into each other, that's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only `a` tag ll be focousable so use below code it'll work...i have updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satya6565/9bo81jyy/10/)

```
.nav > ul.navtabs > li > a:focus .delete{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `<div tabindex="0" class="delete">` is not available in the DOM because of this CSS:

```
.delete{
  display: none;
}
```

So that `<div>` can never be clicked on and can never receive focus.

Instead try focus on the `<a>` tag:

```
ul.navtabs a:focus .delete{
  display: inline !important;
}
```

And remove the `tabindex="0"` on the `<div>`.